# Jquerymobile Page Redirecting with URL through JSP?

Tags: jsp, redirect, jquery-mobile

Here i have a problem with redirecting the URL with JSP Form submit the page (use post method ) is Changing But the URL is not Changing.......

the page sequence:

```
index.jsp -> redirect.jsp -> somePage.jsp
```

`index.jsp` file have include `jqm js` and `css`

here is my mobileinit settings :

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false; });
```

redirect.jsp file

```
<%response.sendRedirect( "somePage.jsp" );%>
```

It's strange that is work when `index.jsp` without  include `jqm js and css.`